# Angular Controller Not loading : Error: [ng:areq] Argument Controller is not a function, got undefined

Tags: javascript, angularjs

angular.js:13540 Error: [ng:areq] Argument 'PropertiesCtrl' is not a function, got undefined

I keep getting my controller isn't not a function and I can't determine why. If I copy the code from the propertiesCtrl.js and paste it in the app.js it works. But I can't seem to get it to work via a seperate file.

Thank you for your help in advance. Sorry for the newb question.

```
File Structure
Property Manager
-app
--properties
---propertiesCtrl.js
-css
-img
-js
--app.js
--libs
---(angular, UI, other vendor files(
-server.js
-views
--main.html
--about.html
-index.html
```

index.html

```
<!-- Angular and Controllers -->
<script src="/js/libs/angular.js"></script>
<script src="/js/libs/angular-route.js"></script>
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-ui-router/0.4.2/angular-ui-router.min.js"></script>
<script src="/js/app.js"></script>
<script src="app/properties/propertiesCtrl.js"></script>

<span ng-controller="PropertiesCtrl as props">{{ props.name }}</span>
```

app.js

```
angular.module('app', ['ui.router']);

//configure our routes
angular.module('app').config(function ($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {
$urlRouterProvider.otherwise("/");

   var mainState = {
       name: 'main',
       url: '/',
       templateUrl: 'views/main.html'
   };


$stateProvider.state(mainState);
});
```

propertiesCtrl.js

```
function propertiesCtrl() {
   this.name = 'Properties 1';
}

angular.module('app').controller('PropertiesCtrl', propertiesCtrl);
```

New Error

[New Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1tccv.png)

Comment: Where did my comments go?

Comment: Does the script  `src="app/properties/propertiesCtrl.js` loaded succesfully in the browser?